# How to show input tensor with tensorboard in Keras

Tags: keras, tensorboard

I'm using Keras for training a image classifier. Now I want to check whether the input images fed to my ConvNet are correct, I want to show them with tensorbard in Keras.

After search on google, some answers say I need to implement a subclass of Keras tensorboard callback like the following:

```
class TensorBoardImage(keras.callbacks.Callback):
def __init__(self, tag):
    super().__init__() 
    self.tag = tag

def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    # Load image
    img = data.astronaut()
    # Do something to the image
    img = (255 * skimage.util.random_noise(img)).astype('uint8')

    image = make_image(img)
    summary = tf.Summary(value=[tf.Summary.Value(tag=self.tag, image=image)])
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./logs')
    writer.add_summary(summary, epoch)
    writer.close()

    return
```

But how can I pass my input image tensor into this callback?
If any one know how to do?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to to just save your images with matplot lib. It is going to be easier and there is no need to get into world of tf.Summary. If you are still interested in doing so, you will need to use tf.image_summary.